# ASCII character for integer 650

Tags: c, ascii

This code prints question mark with white filled block.
What is the ASCII code here? I do not find it in the table. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  
   int i = 650;

   printf("%c\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ASCII characters are 0 to 255

Comment: @EdHeal: 0 to 127, in fact; characters 128-255 usually display as something but it's not the ASCII standard that defines them.

Comment: See wikipage about [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Answer (score 2):

650 (decimal) is equivalent to 0x28a (hexadecimal).
The format `%c` is taking the lower 8-bits of that, attempting to print 0x8a.
In ASCII, there is no character defined for 0x8a, so [for your system] the inverted-color question mark is being displayed as a substitute.

Comment: According to the C standards, if no length modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written.

Comment: @whydoubt You are correct. I was also thinking the same but I was erroneously expecting it to print extended ASCII for 0x28a which is non-standard